# Compare two different values in c++

Tags: c++, qt

I iterate over a QByteArray which contains words. I will compare the array content with a given word (QString).

```
for(QByteArray::iterator it = content.begin(); it != content.end(); it++){
    if(content.at(*it) == word){
        ...
    }
}
```

the compiler say on line (`if(content.at ..)`) : invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

how can i compare the values in this case?

Chris

Comment: You basically extract the bytes (`char` in this case) from the array. Then you are asking Qt to compare the single char with your word. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: `I iterate over a QByteArray which contains words`. That sentence makes no sense to me. Do you mean it contains a single word, or multiple concatenated words?

Comment: thats right, I mean: I iterate over an qbytearray which contains words from a file. I will compare each word with a given word.

Comment: @user1895683: no you arne't.  You're comparing each _letter_ with a given word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I iterate over an qbytearray which contains words from a file. I will compare each word with a given word.

Thanks for the clarification. In that case<sup>1</sup> I would convert the `QByteArray` to `QString` and then split it into individual words which can then be trivially compared.

```
// QByteArray is implicitly convertible to QString
QString allWords = yourByteArray;
// split the string at each whitspace or newline
QStringList aWordlist = allWords.split(QRegExp("[\s\r\n]"), QString::SkipEmptyParts)

for (QStringList::iterator it=aWordlist.begin(); it != aWordlist.end(); ++it) 
{ 
   // it points to the next word in the list
   if (*it == word)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

<sup>1</sup>I'm assuming that you can't change the fact that you receive the file contents as byte array. Otherwise, it would probably be better to open a `QFile` and read the contents from there.

---

> How can i compare the values in this case?

According to the [QString documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html), `QString` can be compared to `QByteArray` without iterating. So you could simply say:

```
QString word("Hello");
QByteArray bytes("hi");

if (word == bytes)
{ 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`QByteArray` contains bytes. `QString` contains a string, that is a sequence of characters. A single byte cannot be compared to a sequence of bytes.

Comment: While accurate, this says little more than the compiler error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`*it` is a byte and you try to compare it to a word(i.e. a sequence of chars). I am not sure what you are trying to do but maybe you should compare `content.at(*it)` to the first char in the word?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you want to do and the problem is not so much with the comparison as with the fact that you have stored your text in a `QByteArray` rather than a `QString`, or some kind of container such as a `QVector`, etc.

You need to look into different ways of reading in data from the `QFile` class.  Check out the docs here:

[QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qfile.html#details)

[QIODevice](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#details)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem: (`QString word;`)

```
void MainWindow::startSearching()
{
    word = ui->passwordTxt->toPlainText();
    string a;
    fstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(fileName.data());

    while(!inputFile.eof()){
        inputFile >> a;
        if(a == word.toStdString()){
       //anything
            break;
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```